# Port not opening even after adding security group rules on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, port, groups

I have an Amazon EC2 Linux instance. I recently installed SmartFoxServer in my instance. For that I needed to open 9933 port. So I just created inbound rules on Amazon EC2 Manager console website.

My rule is

> Custom - TCP Rule - TCP - 9933 - 0.0.0.0/0

But still my port is remain closed. Am unable to connect. Anything else I need to do after adding rules on security groups?

http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
here in above url I checked whether my port is opened or not. Its closed

Comment: That site isn't a good test.  I've just verified through testing that it reports everything not "open" (accepting connections) as "closed" and those are not the only possibilities, nor is it enough information.  What happens if you try to connect with nc or telnet? (`telnet x.x.x.x 9933`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with wildfly server instead of SmartFox server so assuming you did try telnet and/or nc and still failed to reach the server at desired port, below is the fix that might work for you as well:

Wildfly instance (in your case Smartfox), according to configration file, was binding ports (in your case, 9933) with the network inrerface **lo** (loopback) and not with **eth0** whereas all the rules in **security groups** apply to the interface facing the VPC i.e. **eth0**.

When I tweaked my wildfly configuration file to bind the ports with right interface, everything worked as expected whereas previously I was not able to telnet/nc to *destination:port*